# unicode to utf-8 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have output from a server like

```
["alex", "\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd"]
```

i want to convert it like 
    ["alex", "to its right language"]
using js or jquery

i tried

```
function encode_utf8( s )
{
   return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) )
}
```

but not working correctly

any help?
thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using to fetch the output? This looks like JSON encoded data and it should be decoded automatically by whatever you use to fetch it

Comment: `\ufffd` is the [Replacement Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) code. Seems like the data is already messed up on the server, you won't be able to recover it in your Javascript.

Comment: My server is ruby on rails and it is a json response, can't recover it by js ?

Comment: @M.SH You can't fix anything when you're receiving garbage. Where are you getting the data from? It seems like the problem is in the server-side scripting, not on the client.

Comment: `\ufffd` is `�`, which means the text has been messed up.

Comment: If it's literally a bunch of `\ufffd`s, then the original Unicode is long gone, messed up somewhere upstream of you.  Real Unicode would have a variety of different values after the `\u`'s.

Comment: Maybe you need to download the file itself, not the rendered content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you mean by getting output "LIKE" the shown example...

but if you get `["alex", "\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd"]` and assign it to a variable like

```
var foo = ["alex", "\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd"];
// alert(foo[1]) results in "��������" which actually means
// the engine has at least tried to resolve the characters
```

for example if you pass in correct character codes like:

```
var foo = ["alex", "\u003cp\u003emy UTF paragraph\u003c/p\u003e"];
// alert(foo[1]) results in "<p>my UTF paragraph</p>" which seems correct to me...
```

Try the examples above in a browser console (works at least for me in current Chrome)

On the other hand if you receive `"\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd"` every time then I assume similar to the commentors that your response already gets messed up before you are handling it in JavaScript

This [article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) shows nicely that using Unicode characters is valid for variable naming so the same should apply to string content.

Comment: Thank u , the commenters and you are right, the mistake with from the server.